# SQL Count and Inner Joins multiplying my results

Tags: sql

Looking for some help. I am new to SQL and I don't understand my issue at all.

Below I am showing my code, the results I see when I run the code and a details of the actual results it should show

SQL Code

[image: SQL Code]

SQL Results

[image: SQL Results]

Actual Results should show,

```
No NCR are in fact 1
No MRB are in fact 1
No BA are infact 3
```

No Total PO’s are infact 107

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: The comma-separated joins you are using were made redundant in 1992. You shouldn't use them anymore. Use proper ANSI joins instead, e.g. `from supplier_info_general sig join ncr_cfv ncr on sig.name = ncr.cf$_ncr_supplier`.

Comment: The number of total POs are obviously 106, not 107. 1x1x3x106=318. 318x5=1590. 318x10=3180. 318x16=5088.

Comment: @Ryan Wilson: That is very wrong.

Comment: @Jamie Baird: Had you pasted the query and result as text and not as images, you might have gotten upvotes instead of downvotes. Your problem is a common beginner's mistake, so your request and my answer :-) may help people in the future. Per supplier you are combining all business activities with all purchase orders, which makes no sense. See my answer on this.

Answer (score -1):

I'll try with a small example: A person has friends and family members.

**family**

- Mum
- Dad

**friends**

- Fred
- George

If you do this:

```
select person, count(family.member), count(friends.friend)
from family
join friends using (person);
```

then per person you take all friends and all family members and combine them:

```
person   friend   family
123      Fred     Mum
123      Fred     Dad
123      George   Mum
123      George   Dad
```

because all records are for person 123 and this is the only criteria on which you join. The counts are both 4, because you count rows where the friend or family member is not null, which is true for all joined rows.

You don't want to join friends with family members, because they are not directly related. What you want to do instead is joining *the number of* family members with *the number of* friends per person.

```
select person, coalesce(fam.cnt, 0), coalesce(frd.cnt, 0)
from 
  (select person, count(*) as cnt from family group by person) fam
full outer join
  (select person, count(*) as cnt from friends group by person) frd using (person);
```

I.e. aggregate before joining.

Comment: Whoever downvoted my answer: Next time please leave a comment as to what you don't like about it. I think my answer illustrates very well the issue in OP's query. OP said they were new to SQL, so I thought an eloborate answer would be good. I also made comments on the request that should help further.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten Kettner.........I will try and amend. Thanks for your help, I am a beginner so any advice is appreciated